# Jquery click on anchor and get value

Tags: jquery, html

I have these anchors generated by php script:

```
<a href="#" class="remFile"> Leaf </a>
<a href="#" class="remFile"> Flower </a>
<a href="#" class="remFile"> Branches </a>
<a href="#" class="remFile"> Seeds </a>
```

I need to click on e.g. Flower and alert "flower";

I used jquery:

```
alert( $(".remFile").html()); // output 1st item "Leaf" on any anchor clicked
```

I also tried:

```
alert( $(".remFile").text()); // output all values on any anchor clicked
```

If it is not possible, can you please suggest some other solutions? like using < li > ?

Comment: You collected some *not-accepted* answers... Is really possible that none of the provided answers helped you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('a.remFile').click(function(){ alert($(this).text()) })
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/D7AEE/)**

Answer (score 2):

You can use `$(this)` to target current clicked anchor as well as **[text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** to get the text of your anchor:

```
$('a.remFile').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent default action of your anchor which will reload the page
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cdb3V/)**

Answer (score 1):

just use this to refer to current anchor

```
alert($(this).text();

$('a').click(function(){
alert($(this).text());
});
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VBE74/1/)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$(".remFile").click(function(){ alert($(this).html())});
```

Answer (score 1):

use this -

```
$('.remFile').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); // or return false;
   alert($(this).html());
});
```

Live demo : [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/sharif084/p7TD3/)

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand you want to do this:

```
$(".remFile").click(function(){
    alert($(this).html());
});
```